# How to improve AWS amplify auth sign in speed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using expo and AWS Amplify("aws-amplify": "^1.1.26") to do authentication.

My workflow for login is simple , check if I'm able to get values, store in redux, turn off spinner and move to next page.

The issue is that for login (mobile data/wifi), it takes an approximate 6-10 seconds to get a response from Auth.signIn method.

Is there any configuration or steps needed to improve the authentication speed?
The reason being the login page is my app's first impression and the loading time will definitely not impress anyone.

Code Snippet as follows

```
 Auth.signIn(username, password)
  .then(user => {
    if (user.attributes.email_verified == true) {
    this.setState({ user });
    //Redux store some values
    ...
    //Turn off spinner
    this.setState({
      loading: false
    });
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Page2');
```

Comment: Check which region you chose when initialising Amplify. Maybe you chose another continent?

Comment: Would give it a go , could be an likely issue to this. Thanks!

Comment: @Gene did you able to resolve this issue? We are also facing the same issue. We have react app on S3 in region us-east-1. It takes more than 8 seconds to login with AWS Cognito using amplify.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @danish I think you can try the region to where you are located. I eventually sticked with the original region as I do not have the time to change. Mine is currently around 3-5 seconds for login at the moment.